# Indirectly having interface property

Tags: c#

I have an interface that looks like this:

```
interface IName
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

and a Class like this:

```
public class ClassN
    {
        public int N { get; set; }
    }
```

`N` in this Class N is an int, and the interface requires a string `Name`.
I want the int `N` to be converted to string and to be counted as `Name` in the interface.

So that when I do T.name I get the .N.toString().

Is this possible?

```
Name = N.ToString();
```

Example:

`N = 2;` than `Name = 2;` (but as string)

Comment: Yes.. it is possible... Did you try?

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: You want a _name_ to be an integer? That doesn't make sense. Can you [edit] your post with a more concrete example? You seem to be going against the very idea of interfaces. Why do you have a property called `N`? It _must_ be called `Name`.

Comment: How you implemente the Name property? Can you share that code?

Comment: @Chetan implemente? isn't what is in the class the implementasion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an explicit interface implementation:

```
public class ClassN : IName
{
    string IName.Name
    {
         get { return N.ToString(); }
         set{ if(int.TryParse(value, out int i)) N = i; }
    }
    
    public int N { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic configuration.

```
interface IName<T>
{
    T Name { get; set; }
}
```

If you want a casting related configuration, you can use object.

```
interface IName
{
    object Name { get; set; }
}
```